# amount withdrawal from website seller paypal account to any website user paypal account using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paypal

I have tried to do the payout in sandbox mode which resulted in a declined status as the account is unverified.

I have also tried Adaptive payments, it's working but the problem is that it is redirecting for the session followed by a confirmation to transfer to the account.